# Showing that a subgroup $H\subseteq G$ is contained in its normalizer $N_G(H)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Suppose $G$ is a group and $H \leq G.$ Define a set $$N_G(H)=\lbrace a \in G:aHa^{-1}=H \rbrace.$$ Show that $H \leq N_G(H)$.

I try to use the statement '$H \leq G \iff ab^{-1} \in H\,\,\forall a,b \in H$'. But I got stuck. Can anyone guide me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$aHa^{-1}=\{aha^{-1}\mid h\in H\}.$$
*From now on, let's suppose that $a$ is an element of $H$.*

For any $h\in H$, we have that $aha^{-1}\in H$ because subgroups are closed under taking inverse and products. Thus $aHa^{-1}\subseteq H$.

On your own, now show that any element $g\in H$ is equal to $aha^{-1}$ for some $h\in H$, thereby demonstrating that $H\subseteq aHa^{-1}$.

Thus, for any $a\in H$, we have that $aHa^{-1}=H$, which shows that $H\subseteq N_G(H)$.

Comment: Can you examine my work: Let $g \in H$. Then for $\forall h \in H$, $aha^{-1} \in H \implies aHa^{-1} \subset H \implies H \subset a^{-1}Ha$. Since $H$ is a group, if $a \in H$, then $a^{-1} \in H$. So we have $H \subset aHa^{-1} \implies aHa^{-1}=H \implies a \in N_G(H)$

Comment: @Idonknow: Your phrasing is a bit unclear, but it looks okay. I think a more straightforward statement of the same argument would just be to note that, for any $g\in H$, we have $g=aha^{-1}$ when $h=a^{-1}ga$ (and $aga^{-1}\in H$ because $a\in H$ and $g\in H$) so that any $g\in H$ is also an element of $aHa^{-1}$, so that $H\subseteq aHa^{-1}$.

Comment: If $g \in H$, isn't $gHg^{-1}=H$?

Comment: @Idonknow: Well, that's what my answer is helping you to show, isn't it? :) Once we know that $gHg^{-1}=H$ for any $g\in H$, then we clearly have that
$$H\subseteq\{g\in G\mid gHg^{-1}=H\}.$$
My hint was to show that, for any $g\in H$, we have $gHg^{-1}\subseteq H$ and $H\subseteq gHg^{-1}$, which implies that $gHg^{-1}=H$.

Answer (score 0):

First we have if $h$ $\in$ $H$ then $Hh=H$ and $hH=H$,it concludes that $\forall h \in H$,$hHh^{-1}=H$

thus ,which show $H\subseteq N_G(H)$,and $H$ is a group ,therefore 
$H \leq N_G(H)$.

Comment: can you explain why $hHh^{-1}=H$?

Comment: @Idonknow if$ a\in Hb$ then $Ha=Hb$,it is a theorem.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

> I try to use the statement '$H \leq G \iff ab^{-1} \in H\,\,\forall a,b \in H$'.

This statement proves that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Since we already know that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, the only thing left to show is that $H$ is contained in $N_G(H)$.

Let $h\in H$ and we will show that $h\in N_G(H)$. That is, by definition of $N_G(H)$, we will show that $hHh^{-1}=H$. Indeed, since $H$ is a subgroup, we have for all $a \in H$ : $aH=H$ and $Ha=H$ (because a subgroup is closed under multiplication). So $hHh^{-1}=H$.